# Cancel animation in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm using `JQuery animation` plugin for `ul` elements taken from [this](http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial) tutorial but when swapping the mouse fast between all the `li` elements it's freeking out and keep moving from side to side.

how can I stop the animation?  I'm sure it can done with the [dequeqe](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) function. But didn't succeeded.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/kLLDX/)

Comment: Have you tried [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)? There are [many related questions on SO as well](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+stop+animation).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop .hover animation when the mouse leaves in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786873/stop-hover-animation-when-the-mouse-leaves-in-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(this).stop(true).animate //etc
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLLDX/2/

Comment: Thanks, why are you stopping only `this` and not all the items?

Comment: @gdoron Np, `this` refers to the element which is currently beeing hovered, thus only stopping the animation for the element who requires it. Selecting all items instead of `this` would result in the entire collection moving simultaneously